# Excel VBA inserting missing dates

Tags: xml, vba, excel

Hi I'm pretty new to vba and I have been trying for a long time to figure this out but can't seem to crack it.

i have a workbook with several sheets, and in the even numbered sheets there are dates in `yyyy-mm-dd` format in column a, and data in columns b through whatever (it varies).

Excel doesn't seem to be able to recognize these as dates, and I need to use a formula that finds missing dates in each sheet and then inserts a new row with the missing date (and blanks for the column's b thru however wide that sheet is).

I have gotten lost just trying to convert the dates to `mm/dd/yy` so that Excel will at least recognize them as dates.

my code is not great, but I have so far really only figured out how to loop across the even numbered sheets and insert blank columns.

```
 Sub add_columns()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim ws_num As Integer



    Dim starting_ws As Worksheet
    Set starting_ws = ActiveSheet
    ws_num = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

        For i = 2 To ws_num Step 2
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Activate
                    Range("B1").EntireColumn.Insert
                    Range("B:D").EntireColumn.Insert

                 **For x = 2 to #ROWS in column B
                    cell.b"x" = MID(b"x",3,2) 
                    cell.c"x" = mid(a"x",6,2)
                    cell.d"x" = left(a"x",2)
                    cell.e"x" = c"x" / d"x" / b"x"
                 next**

        Next   
End Sub
```

The stuff between the stars is what I can't figure out, and this would really only give me dates in the right format, but even that would be a big help.

After that I would try to write something to look across the dates, determine if a cell is equal to the previous plus one, if not insert new row, make date cell equal to the previous plus one, check again etc etc.

Thanks

Comment: Excel should recognize that format as a date in most locales. What is your locale? What exactly is in those cells?  And how do you know that Excel is not recognizing it as a date?

Comment: Try using DateValue function to convert text date into real date. DateValue("2018-04-01") will give you 43191, which you can format as you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

To help you with the date conversion. You could check your locale, and check if DateValue works for you.

In terms of converting a date in 'yyyy-mm-dd' format using string functions, you could do it in vba as follows:

```
myDate = dateSerial(left("a" & x, 4),mid("a" & x, 6,2), mid("a" & x, 9,2))
```